# Unable to deploy Jenkins to Kubernetes using official guide

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I'm trying to install Jenkins on Kubernetes with its official guide: [at Jenkins's site](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/), **Install Jenkins with Helm v3**. The environment is Linux/Minikube.

1. I created namespace Jenkins
2. Created Persistent Volume with [the yaml provided](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/master/content/doc/tutorials/kubernetes/installing-jenkins-on-kubernetes/jenkins-volume.yaml)
3. Created [service account](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/master/content/doc/tutorials/kubernetes/installing-jenkins-on-kubernetes/jenkins-sa.yaml)
4. Installed with `helm install jenkins -n jenkins -f jenkins-values.yaml jenkinsci/jenkins` where values are official too
   I only alerted Jenkins values as it was recommended in the instruction (added values below):

```
storageClass: jenkins-pv
...
serviceAccount:
  create: false
```

**The issue:** Jenkins pod never starts.
*It says: “0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn’t find available persistent volumes to bind. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling…”*

**PV** is created:

```
rage@ubuntu-virtual:~$ kubectl describe pv jenkins -n jenkins
Name:            jenkins-pv
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    jenkins-pv
Status:          Released
Claim:           default/jenkins
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        5Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /data/jenkins-volume/
    HostPathType:  
Events:            <none>
```

**PVC** says: “WaitForPodScheduled”

```
$ kubectl describe pvc jenkins -n jenkins
Name:          jenkins
Namespace:     jenkins
StorageClass:  jenkins-pv
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        app.kubernetes.io/component=jenkins-controller
               app.kubernetes.io/instance=jenkins
               app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
               app.kubernetes.io/name=jenkins
               helm.sh/chart=jenkins-4.3.23
Annotations:   meta.helm.sh/release-name: jenkins
               meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: jenkins
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       jenkins-0
Events:
  Type    Reason               Age                   From                         Message
  ----    ------               ----                  ----                         -------
  Normal  WaitForPodScheduled  38m (x481 over 160m)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for pod jenkins-0 to be scheduled
  Normal  WaitForPodScheduled  28m (x26 over 34m)    persistentvolume-controller  waiting for pod jenkins-0 to be scheduled
  Normal  WaitForPodScheduled  2m35s (x81 over 22m)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for pod jenkins-0 to be scheduled
```

Pod's describe:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  37s   default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
```

Please, help investigate to this problem. I quess its PVC-related, but can't catch where exactly the problem is.

**UPDATE**

Also I tried to add nodeAffinity to my PersistentVolume, with no success. I put **minikube** here, because I'm developing locally

```
nodeAffinity:
required:
  nodeSelectorTerms:
  - matchExpressions:
    - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
      operator: In
      values:
      - minikube
```

Also I added claimRef with name Jenkins. Jenkins Helm installation creates PVC with this name.

```
   claimRef:
    name: jenkins
    namespace: jenkins
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue.
Got actual Jenkins volume claim, which was deployed with Helm-chart:

> kubectl get pvc jenkins -n jenkins -o yaml

It stated:

```
      resources:
      requests:
      storage: 8Gi
```

And my volume size was lesser: 5Gi. Thats why PVC request was not satisfied.
Very strange, that there wasn't any particular notice from Kubernetes about it when I did '**describe**' command for PVC/pod.

So I adjusted values.yaml, provided with Jenkins Helm chart to acquire lesser size:

```
  storageClass: jenkins-pv
  annotations: {}
  labels: {}
  accessMode: "ReadWriteOnce"
  size: "5Gi"
```

Now it works as intended. So there is no glitches in the official documentation related to this case.

Answer (score 0):

The yaml of pv at [jenkins's site](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/) has nodeSelector like below

```yaml
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - worker-node01
```

have you replaced **worker-node01** to your nodeName?

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't helped. I wrote additional details in the UPDATE section.